# Mocking a service class inside controller

Tags: laravel, testing, mocking, laravel-8

I am trying to write a Feature test for my controller. To simplify my current situation, imagine my controller looks like this:

```
public function store(Business $business)
{
   try {
      (new CreateApplicationAction())->execute($business);
   } catch (Exception $e) {
      return response()->json(['message' => 'error'], 500);
   }

   return response()->json(['message' => 'success']);
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is, instead of testing CreateApplication class logic inside my integration test, I want to write another unit test for it specifically.

Is there a way I can simply say `CreateApplicationAction` expects `execute()` and bypass testing inside it? (without executing the code inside `execute()`)

```
/** @test */
public function can_create_application()
{
    $business = Business:factory()->create();

    $mock = $this->mock(CreateApplicationAction::class, function (MockInterface $mock) use ($business) {
         $mock->shouldReceive('execute')
             ->once()
             ->with($business)
             ->andReturn(true);
    });

    $response = $this->post('/businesses/3/application', $data);

    $response->assertOk();
}
```

---

I saw online that people create "MockCreateApplicationAction" class but if possible I don't want to create another class as I don't want any logic to be inside it at all.

Is it possible?

```
class CreateApplicationAction
{
    public function execute($business) {
        dd("A");

        // Business Logic...
    }
}
```

So when I do the Mock, `dd()` should never be called. Or I am going in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use `Laravels` container to resolve your class. The basic approach is to use the `resolve()` method helper. PHP does not have dependency injection, so you need to use one to make it possible, in `Laravel` the container solves that.

```
resolve(CreateApplicationAction::class)->execute($business);
```

On constructors, controller methods, jobs, events, listeners and commands (rule of thumb if the method is named handle), you can inject classes into the parameters and they will resolve through the container.

```
public function store(Business $business, CreateApplicationAction $applicationAction)
{
    try {
        $applicationAction->execute($business);
```